# Things around $(\forall x)(\Psi \Rightarrow \Phi) \Leftrightarrow ((\exists z)\Psi) \Rightarrow \Phi)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Let $M,N$ be sets, $Q_M$ a set that depends on $M$ and $P(\cdot,\cdot)$ a property with two parameters (is it ok, to call these "parameters" or would "variables" have been better ?). Consider the following three statements:

*i)* $(\forall x\in M)(\forall y\in Q_M)[P(x,y)\Rightarrow x \in N]$

*ii)* $(\forall x\in M)[((\exists y\in Q_M)[P(x,y)])\Rightarrow x \in N]$

*iii)* $N=\{ x\in M \mid (\exists y\in Q_M)[P(x,y)]\}$

I would very much like to know the following:

1. I have been told that *i)* and *ii)* are equivalent, since they are an instance of a general scheme
   $$
   (\forall x)(\Psi \Rightarrow \Phi) \Leftrightarrow  ((\exists z)\Psi) \Rightarrow \Phi), 
   $$
   which holds if $z$ is not mentioned in $\Phi$, as Carl Mummert I think explained a long time ago  - I can't find the entry right now.
   What are the "values" the $x,z,\Psi$ and $\Phi$ have to take, such that this scheme shows the equivalence of *i)* and *ii)* ?
2. What kind of setting do you need in which you can prove this general scheme ? Is it only predicate logic ? Or do you need ZFC to formalize this logic so you can you use set-theory to prove it ?
3. How to you prove it (or a corrected version of it, if the above is flawed; it seems to me that quantifiers are missing) ?
4. Is *ii)* equivalent to *iii)* ? How do you *rigorously* prove that ? Which ZFC axioms are needed for that proof ?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus  Using lattice theory ? I can't imagine how that could work... Maybe you mean that there is a formal analogy between similar looking statements in lattice theory and these ones ? Also, what is ZDF ?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

1]  Assuming that $x$ is not free in $\varphi$, here's a chain of equivalences:

> (a) $\forall x(\psi(x) \to \varphi)$
>
> (b) $\forall x(\neg\psi(x) \lor \varphi)$
>
> (c) $\forall x\neg\psi(x) \lor \varphi$
>
> (d) $\neg\forall x\neg\psi(x) \to \varphi$
>
> (e) $\exists x\psi(x) \to \varphi$

The only step that might give you pause is the equivalence of (b) and (c): it might help to compare $(\neg\psi(a) \lor \varphi) \land (\neg\psi(b) \lor \varphi)$ and $(\neg\psi(a) \land \neg\psi(b)) \lor \varphi$. Note that equivalence of (a) and (e) is just a matter of first-order logic, and nothing to do with ZFC.

2] These are also equivalents:

> (a')  $(\forall x \in A)(\psi(x) \to \varphi)$
>
> (b')  $(\exists x \in A)\psi(x) \to \varphi$

by just the same kind of reasoning, and again just by appeal to first-order logic. You just need to unpack the abbreviations for restricted quantifiers.

3] To see your (i) implies (ii), instantiate (i) -- use a parameter to name an arbitrary object in $M$ -- apply an (a'/b')-type equivalence, and generalize to get (ii). You can then do the reverse equivalence.

Comment: I don't really understand 3]. What is an (a'/b')-type equivalence ? Also, wouldn't I need two objects $M_1,M_2$ to instantiate with, since I have two quantifiers ? Or did you mean to show the equivalence between (ii) and (iii) ? Since your numbering differs from mine, I'm somewhat confused what is proved where. (Could you please also answer my question 1. ?)

Comment: In case you really meant (i) and (ii) in 3], what is an "object" ? Since we are outside of set-theory I thought I would only have syntactic rules at my disposal that tell me how to manipulate first-order formulas...

Comment: An (a'/b')-type equivalence is an equivalence of the kind illustrated by the pair (a'), (b') above. I meant your (i) and (ii). You only need to instantiate the outermost quantifiers to expose a pair of wffs of the relevant (a'/b')-types. I've replaced "object" with "parameter naming an object" (which should help explain what was obviously meant in context). Hope that helps.